# Estimator asymptotically unbiased

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

Why at the point of the solution highlighted in red can I not just say:

as there is a consistent sequence of MLE's i.e $\bar{X}  \rightarrow  \theta$ in probability we have that:

$e^{-\bar{X}} \rightarrow e^{-\theta}$ hence,

$E(e^{-\bar{X}}) \rightarrow E(e^{-\theta})=e^{-\theta}$ hence,

$E(e^{-\bar{X}})$ is asymptotically unbiased?

Comment: In general,  $X_n \to_P \theta$ doesn't imply $E[X_n] \to \theta$ without further conditions.

Comment: To add to what @Solitary wrote... although your conclusion $E(e^{-\bar X} )\to e^{-\theta}$ is correct, it is *not* because $e^{-\bar X} \to e^{-\theta}$ (this is merely a necessary condition).